# Understanding the use of a generic dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

Whenever I see code like this my head hurts. Can anyone explain what this is doing?

```
public static class MyExtensionFirADictionary
{
    public static TValue <TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key)
    { 
        TValue value;
        if (dic != null && dic.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;

        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile....

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance correct, it needs a name :)

Comment: You forget to _name_ part of this method. This won't compile or course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laymans terms

//First add a method name to your example extension method so it compiles

```
public static class MyExtensionFirADictionary
{
   public static TValue GetGenericValue <TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key)
   { 
       TValue value;
       if (dic != null && dic.TryGetValue(key, out value))
           return value;

       return default(TValue);
   }
}
```

now lets start at the beginning:

method signature:

```
       public static TValue GetGenericValue <TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key)
```

Return an object of type TValue i.e.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

In this case if you called

```
dict.GetGenericValue("thekey");
```

TValue would be of type int (note the `<string, int>` and relate it to you original method

IMPORTANT IDEAS TO UNDERSTAND:

Think of generics as templating. The TValue, TKey are just placeholders which you specify when you do this:

```
List<myclass>
```

HTH

Comment: you are welcome - sometimes the hardest part to get is the concept :)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the compilation errors, that just says "return the value held against the key, if one - otherwise return the default value of the dictionary", via an extension method. The name isn't shown, but it could be used via something like:

```
string name = nameLookup.GetValueOrDefault(userId);
```

Note that the compiler handles a the generics implicitly - the caller doesn't need to specify them.

First, the code checks whether the dictionary is null; if it is null it just returns the default value.

The TryGetValue is a standard dictionary method that does the lookup and returns true if it worked; the code uses that method, and returns the fetched value if there was one - else it explicitly uses the default value for TValue.

Comment: its looks crazy, why is it so complicated?  Im not sure how to learn this code.  If I just look for tutorial on generics I get silly noddy examples but this is something quite different?

Comment: @James which bit are you finding complicated?

Comment: I struggle with the TValue tbh.

Comment: @JamesRadford, would you find it easier to read if you needed to box/unbox every single value? The whole point of generics is to make things easier. After you get used to it, you'll see it too. Try to start with simpler examples and compare it with "older" way of programming the same logic. I bet you'll start to see the benefits very quickly.

Comment: @JamesRadford it is for Generics, allowing it to be used with whatever type you'd like.  So the extension method will work on any dictionary, be it `Dictionary<string, string>`, `Dictionary<int, string>`, etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think you have gone a it far - I think it is clear this is not a case where the OP doesnt understand the finer points I think the OP just doesnt understnd generics. Regards

Answer (score 0):

it allows for the same functionality as the default dictionary behavior, but makes it easier to use.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//add items to dictionary
```

so the default would be something like this:

```
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey("someKey"))
    {
        var value = dictionary["someKey"];
    }
```

however if it doesn't have that key, and you dont do a ContainsKey check, an exception will be thrown.  What the extension method does, it does a TryGetValue, which checks if the key exists, if so returns the value else, returns default(T)

the new use would be (assuming the name of the extension method is GetValue):

```
var value = dictionary.GetValue("someKey");
```

a lot shorter and cleaner.